# What are the differences between the FlatList created via. `Animated.FlatList` and `Animated.createAnimatedComponent(FlatList)`?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-reanimated-v2

What are the main differences between these two `FlatList` components?

Note: Animated is imported from 'react-native-reanimated' in both instances.